# Salesforce Community page not opening

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

My community site has been working fine since yesterday 10 AM IST. But after that when ever I try to login it throws an error saying
When I try to check what is the problem. I navigate to administration section through builder
it throws an error
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error in $A.getCallback() [Communication error, please retry or reload the page]
Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.communities.components.aura.components.communitySetup.cmc.CMCAppController/ACTION$getAppBootstrapData
Failing descriptor: {markup://communitySetup:cwApp}
Even I am not able to see the login page it says Invalid page when I enter the URL of Login page what might be the issue please help
Thanks in Advance

Solution for this please

This issue happens only in one sandbox. In my R & D and production is working fine
Please help to resolve this issue